# Using Vlookup and IsError

Tags: excel, vba

I am appying vlookup and iferror function like below but iferror function is not working (like incase lookup value doesn't exist)-

```
FX_File = ActiveWorkbook.Name
tab_name = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name
FX_Rate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("AUD", Sheets(tab_name).Range("B1:D100"), 3, False)
If IsError(FX_Rate) Then
    'DO NOTHING
Else
     Workbooks(Filename).Worksheets("Macro").Range("E8").Value = FX_Rate
End If
```

Comment: Please, use `Dim FX_Rate As Variant`,  `FX_Rate = Application.VLookup("AUD", Sheets(tab_name).Range("B1:D100"), 3, False)`. `WorksheetFunction` raises a fatal error in case of not finding a match, but `Application` does not... And try declaring all used variables. This will make your code more robust.

Comment: Please add the location of this code (e.g. `ActiveWorkbook`) and explain which workbook and which worksheet is where located and if e.g. `Workbooks(Filename)` is an open workbook. Just add more detail to remove any confusion. Posting the complete relevant code would be helpful.

Comment: It does not give you any `#NA`. The code as you use it now, I mean...  If you want it **returning something, even in case of not a match**, you may use `FX_Rate = Application.IfError(Application.VLookup("AUD", Sheets(tab_name).Range("B1:D100"), 3, False), "Empty")'. It will return "Empty", or whatever you place in the `IfError` second parameter. But I understood that you want changing the value only if **a match has been found**.